# Bash - subtract two hh:mm values

Tags: bash

I have two variables that are passed into a function which are time strings in HH:MM format.

I'm struggling big time to subtract these 2 variables

```
shop_opening_time=09:30
shop_closing_time=18:00
time_to_opening=$((current_time-shop_closing_time))
time_to_close=$((shop_opening_time-current_time))
```

Please can someone guide me as to how to subtract these? Is there any built-in function in bash?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belong on unix.stackexchange https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/490768

Comment: Thank you @JatinMehrotra. Great answer. The only trouble with that answer is that the close time to open time isn't calculated correctly. If the shop close time is 17:00 & it opens next morning at 10 AM & the time now is say 19:00, the time to open is displayed as 7 hrs instead of 15 hours

Comment: I don't agree that this isn't programming-related, but you are expected to demonstrate at least an attempt of your own. In very brief, the usual solution is to normalize the values to something like seconds since the epoch (midnight January 1 1970 UTC) and then perform the arithmetical operation. But your values don't indicate which day they are on; can we always assume they are on adjacent days, with the opening time on the following day?

Comment: Thank you @tripleee. Yes that assumption is correct. Once closed today, opening is tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no bash builtin for that but it's not that difficult to write it yourself:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
time_to() {
    local delta from_hh from_mm to_hh to_mm
    IFS=':' read from_hh from_mm to_hh to_mm <<< "$(date +%H:%M):$1"
    delta=$(((10#$to_hh * 60 + 10#$to_mm) - (10#$from_hh * 60 + 10#$from_mm)))
    [ $delta -lt 0 ] && ((delta += 1440))
#   printf '%d:%02d\n' $((delta/60)) $((delta%60))
    printf 'from %02d:%02d to %02d:%02d = %d:%02d\n' \
        $((10#$from_hh)) $((10#$from_mm)) \
        $((10#$to_hh)) $((10#$to_mm)) \
        $((delta/60)) $((delta%60))
}
```

```
time_to 09:30
from 13:49 to 09:30 = 19:41

time_to 18:00
from 13:49 to 18:00 = 4:11
```

Comment: Thank you heaps @Fravadona

Comment: Could you please explain the purpose of 10# in your code

Comment: inside `(( ))`, numbers that start with `0` are considered octals; to make sure that it is interpreted as a decimal I set the base with `10#`

Comment: Hello Fravadona - Would you be able to help me with another one please - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70430185/remove-duplicate-entries-in-file-optimise-performance